# Command not working when run from Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have cut out a piece of my Bash script that I cannot get to function as it should. I want to copy the content of the folder **gmp-5.0.4** into **gcc-4.6.3/gmp** these packages have been unpacked earlier in the script:

```
GMP_PACKAGE=ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-5.0.4.tar.bz2
GCC_PACKAGE=http://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.3/gcc-core-4.6.3.tar.bz2

copy_math_libraries()
{
        LOCATION="$1"

        mkdir "$LOCATION/gmp"
        cp -v -r "$PACKAGES/`basename $GMP_PACKAGE .tar.bz2`/*" "$LOCATION/gmp"
}

copy_math_libraries "$PACKAGES/`basename $GCC_PACKAGE .tar.bz2 | sed s/core-//`"
```

When running the script with set -x I get the following output:

```
++ cp -v -r '/home/klaus/toolchain/packages/gmp-5.0.4/*' /home/klaus/toolchain/packages/gcc-4.6.3/gmp
cp: cannot stat `/home/klaus/toolchain/packages/gmp-5.0.4/*': No such file or directory
```

If I open another shell and run the exact same command manually everything works as it should:

```
cp -v -r /home/klaus/toolchain/packages/gmp-5.0.4/* /home/klaus/toolchain/packages/gcc-4.6.3/gmp
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the script actually unpacked the archives by the time `copy_math_libraries` gets called?

Comment: You don't run »the exact same command«. Do you see the quotation marks from `set -x` output in your command? Me neither.

Answer (score 2):

Your `*` is not getting expanded.

Try this:

```
cp -v -r "$PACKAGES/`basename $GMP_PACKAGE .tar.bz2`/"* "$LOCATION/gmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

`"…"` prevent shell expansion (globbing). This should fix it:

```
cp -v -r "$PACKAGES/`basename $GMP_PACKAGE .tar.bz2`/"* "$LOCATION/gmp"
```